# c++20 format compiler/stdlib bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, format, clang

Common wisdom says that it's never the compiler but..

```cpp
cout << format("[{:#>{}s}]", "#", 3) << endl;
```

Clang trunk prints `[##]` but MSVC latest prints `[###]`

I discovered this on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7cTGPod4T).

Am I doing something wrong or is one of the two compilers doing something wrong?
And if it's not a mistake on my side which one is wrong and what do I do about this?

Comment: definitely a bug in libc++, but the implementation isn't complete (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777564/cant-use-stdformat-in-c20) so you should probably stick to fmtlib until it is complete

Comment: I was already using fmtlib before so I know how to deal with the issue on my end. What I was referring to was, if and how I should go about reporting the issue or if I should just let libc++ be and wait for them to fix it.

Comment: The libc++ bug tracker would seem to be the obvious place to report bugs?