# clang++ missing header <format> in mac os 12 with clang 13

Tags: c++

```
> g++ -g -Wall -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++  -o nes src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'format' file not found
#include <format>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

> clang++ --version                                                                                                                                          ~/Documents/GitHub/nes
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I tried to update xcode developer tools

How to fix that ?

Where is the std::format header in macos ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777564/cant-use-stdformat-in-c20 - only started in clang 14, not yet complete afaik

Comment: Wikipedia [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_11.x_-_13.x_(since_SwiftUI_framework)) has a mapping of the Xcode version, which is reflected in the clang build version string that comes with Xcode, and the LLVM version it corresponds to.