# std::format errors "no matching function" and "call to consteval function"

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, clion, fmt

Platform: Win 10 64 bit
IDE: CLION 2022.2.4
Toolchain: VS 2022 Community Toolset v17.0 (CMAKE 3.23.2)
Build Tool ninja.exe
C++ compiler: cl.exe

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <format>
    
int main() {
    std::wstring test1 = L"Hällo, ";
    std::wstring test2;
    
    std::cout << std::format("Hello {}\n", "world!");
    std::cout << std::format("Hello {}\n", "world!");
}
```

Errors shown in editor:
[image: Error in first format]
[image: Error in first string]
[image: Error in second string]

I suspect this is a CLang error, but I'm not quite sure. I can compile the code just fine and I get an output to the console. But why do I get an error here?

I tried to find anything on Google on it, but I didn't find anything on this specific error. I know from a friend of mine that this is not an isolated issue, or at least he has the same issue.

From what I read the "consteval" was somewhat newly introduced and might still be incompletely implemented in some library functions?

Comment: when you can compile the code without error, then it is a bug / misconfiguration of the tool that shows the error.

Comment: CLion uses Clang for its "intellisense", but unfortunately only MSVC support `std::format` at this time. So you will get false positives in your editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler that your editor uses for highlighting and intellisense doesn't support those features yet.

[`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) is a c++20 feature. [According to this page](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) it is not yet supported in Clang. This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777564/cant-use-stdformat-in-c20).

Comment: Aaah, okay. Damn, in my search it didn't even cross my mind, that this is a new feature. Okay, that explains it, I guess.

Comment: Correct. Could you please approve my answer if it answered your question? Thank you and good luck :)

Comment: Would that be "clang-tidy" that is causing those problems?

Comment: @J.Baumann yes, I think so. You can try updating that extension or turning it off. You can find the settings for `clang-tidy` in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | C/C++ | General | Clang-Tidy`. I hope it helps.